# NX Client for Windows 7 Opens Remote Desktop in Multiple Windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.10, xfce, nx

What I'm trying to do: access my Ubuntu desktop remotely via NX Client on my Windows 7 laptop.

My environment:

> server: Ubuntu 10.10 on AMD 1Ghz/512MB RAM PC
>
> client: Windows 7 on ThinkPad sl510
>
> Software: server is running NXServer 3.4.0.  Using xfce4 window manager.
>
> Laptop is using NXClient for Windows

In my NX Client "Desktop" settings I've selected "Unix" and "Custom" for OS and environment.  I've also specified "startxfce4" as the application to launch when NX connects.

I am able to authenticate an NX session on my laptop.  By this I mean, I can start the client on my laptop, enter credentials for my Linux user, and NX establishes a connection to the server and attempts to open a remote desktop window.  The problem, though, is that this remote desktop is "fragmented" into many Windows.  One window will display the bulk of my desktop (complete with desktop icons for "Home," "File System," and "Trash") while another window will contain the taskbar, and another window will contain the application strip.  I can select each of these Windows individually, but I cannot click on any objects within them.

I've searched Super User, Ubuntu Forums, NX help, Server Fault, and tried many Google searches - none have turned up another case of this particular problem.  I'm stumped.  Does anyone have any suggestions for what I might try?

I'm guessing the problem has to do with my xfce config files, but I've only just setup this server - it's been a long time since I've used Linux and there's a lot I just don't know.

What I am NOT trying to do: use Desktop sharing from Ubuntu, whereby I VNC into a desktop that I've already established on the server.  I am trying to configure this Linux box as a headless server that I can stash someplace out-of-the-way in my house, then interact with through my laptop.  I don't want to have a monitor or keyboard connected to the Linux box.

Thanks for your help!

edit: 1/19/2011
Well, this is truly bizarre.  To my knowledge I've made no changes to either system - the laptop or the server.  But today after starting up the server for the first time in a few days, and making sure that nxserver was running, I was able to connect with the nxclient from my laptop with no problems.  I have a full desktop in a single window and I am able to interact with it normally.  This is really weird, but the problem seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Same here with xfce4 installed in ubuntu 10.10: running
 `/etc/init.d/nxserver restart` 
was enough to exit the faulty "first server-start" situation. Now I connect normally.